# Input variables to a MATLAB Script through Matlab command window

Tags: matlab, arguments

I wanted to know if there is a way to supply some input arguments that are used in a Matlab script via the Matlab Command Window.

I've seen a bunch of solutions that use a function instead of a script. And some that do the above using Command Prompt and not the Matlab Command Window.
Both are not an option for me.

Also, is there a way to keep the length of the input arguments variable?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a while loop implementation that asks for inputs repeatedly until no input is given and simply the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key is pressed. The if-statement is used to check if the empty, `""` is given as input then stops asking for the next input value. The inputs are all stored in a string array that can be converted to a numeric array using the `str2num()` function if all the inputs are numeric.

```
Index = 1;
Inputs = string;

while (1)
Inputs(Index) = input("Please type inputs: ",'s');
if Inputs(Index) == ""
    break
end
    
Index = Index + 1;
end

Inputs = Inputs(1:end-1);
disp(Inputs);
```

Comment: This is actually great based on my current question, but I guess I forgot to mention that I wanted to enter a bunch of scripts in the command window and let them run without supervision. For that purpose, I would prefer to give the arguments all at once while the previous script is still running. Do you think this will still work?

Comment: Don't think that this would work for that case, but I guess why not pass the inputs simply as an array then you can run the scripts consecutively.